# How to increase test coverage in private method

Tags: swift, tdd

Assume that I'm writing a vector struct

```
struct Vector3d {
    private var v: Double[3]
    init(_ x: Double, _ y: Double, _ z: Double) { v = [x, y, z] }
    init?(value: Double, at index: Int) {
        guard 0...2 ~= index else { return nil }
        v = [0, 0, 0]
        v[index] = value
    }
    var x: Double { return v[0] }
    var y: Double { return v[1] }
    var z: Double { return v[2] }
    var ortho: Vector3d { // return an arbitrary unit vector which is orthogonal to self
        // Idea: find a vector that is not collinear with self and then cross product of that vector and self will be orthogonal to self
        var largestAbsIndex = 0
        largestAbsIndex = fabs(x) > fabs(y) ? fabs(x) > fabs(z) ? 0 : 2 : fabs(y) > fabs(z) ? 1 : 2
        var indexNextToLargest = largestAbsIndex - 1
        if indexNextToLargest < 0 { indexNextToLargest = 2 }
        return (self ** Vector3d(value: 1, at: indexNextToLargest)!).normalized
    }
    static func **(lhs: Vector3d, rhs: Vector3d) -> Vector3d { /* cross product */}
    var normalized: Vector3d { /* some code */ }
}
```

And at some point, I want to make the component index 1-based, i.e. `1...3` instead of `0...2`. I altered the second initializer and corresponding tests, all green

```
init?(value: Double, at index: Int) {
    guard 1...3 ~= index else { return nil }
    v = [0, 0, 0]
    v[index - 1] = value
}
```

Actually, the `ortho` property also depends on the initializer and should be altered as well. But I used `Vector3d(1, 2, 3)` in most of my tests, so when it ran into `ortho` test, it still worked because `largestAbsIndex = 2, indexNextToLargest = 1` -- just lucky. However, `Vector3d(1, 4, 3).ortho` will crash because `largestAbsIndex = 1, indexNextToLargest = 0` and `Vector3d(value: 1, at: 0) == nil`

I observed this bug and it's obvious how to fix it. But TDD suggests that I should first write a test that reveals this bug and then fix the production code. On the other hand, one says that test cases should test behaviors not implementations, so I don't have enough excuse to add a new test of `Vector3d(1, 4, 3).ortho` because it is the concrete implementation details that made these two tests differ.

So, what test should I add to reveal this bug?

This problem arises because the `ortho` getter is doing something not related to it's expected behavior and of course that irrelevant behaviors didn't get tested. I may extract those (i.e. largestAbsIndex, indexNextToLargest) to some other methods and then test them respectively. But there are still problems. These methods of course should be private, whereas I can't and shouldn't test private methods. One says I can extract those methods to another class and test that class if there is an inevitable need for testing private methods. I may extract a `enum` or something like `Vector3dComponentIndex`. But I still can't stand something like that is being public around, because it's meaningful only when used within `Vector3d`

In either approach (extract to private methods or extract to a class/struct/enum that should be private), there is a problem that how to increase the test coverage in private codes?

Comment: How are the tests still passing? If `ortho` is now calling with the incorrect index, doesn't that mean that it's giving the wrong answer (e.g. setting y instead of z) even in cases where the index is still a valid index?

Comment: assume that `a = (0, 0, 1)`, `a.ortho` gives `(-1, 0, 0)` at the beginning and `(0, -1, 0)` after modification, which both satisfies the expectation of "an arbitrary orthogonal vector to self". But if I used `a = (0, 1, 0)` for testing in the first place, `a.ortho` would crash.

Comment: I only test if `a.ortho * a`(which is dot product) equals to 0. I don't test the concrete value of the `ortho` vector because of "test the behavior, not implementation" saying.

Comment: I came up with something after posting this: Firstly, the `ortho` getter function is doing too much things -- 1. find a non-collinear vector. 1.a. find the largestAbsIndex. 1.b. find the indexNextToLargest. 2. construct an orthogonal vector. So I may need to extract the step 1 to some method and add a test for that method, but it's private, how to.... I'm still googling

Comment: I think you've identified the right problem; the magic numbers 0, 1, 2 are in a few places. An enumeration or some contents would DRY that up.

Comment: Yeah, there're plenty of solutions to solve this specific case (either DRY or non-DRY). But I want to know the correct workflow, so I can handle this kind of stuff in future. The problem may abstracted as how to cover sufficient branches in a private method

Comment: I don't think you need to be so rigid on your TDD approach. At the unit testing level it's OK to be aware of the implementation, and if you've identified a possible edge case that's a perfectly good reason to add a test case. The goal is working, robust code, and it's not like you're writing tests that are expected to start failing if you change the implementation (that *would* be too tightly tied to the implementation, and that's what the guideline of not testing implementation is meant to avoid).

Comment: " it's not like you're writing tests that are expected to start failing if you change the implementation" this really dispels my concerns. I should have taken that guideline too dogmatically. BTW, would u write an answer summarizing all these or may I write it myself?

Comment: Dogmatic! That's the word I was trying to think of. I've written an answer, let me know if you feel that doesn't cover it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important thing to think about here is *why* we try to test behaviour rather than implementation. What we're trying to avoid is tests so closely tied to the current implementation that we have to keep changing them all of the time as we refactor or change the implementation. This is one of the benefits of TDD as I see it; it forces you to think first about the interface of that unit, how it will interact with the things around it.

In your case, the assertion you're making is the correct one: the resulting vector must be orthogonal. This is nicely decoupled from any given implementation of the method; *however we write it*, that must be true.

Therefore I think it's perfectly reasonable to either change the current test, or add another one, with a different starting vector to expose the edge case you've identified. That's what you'd do if you were trying to fix it as a bug: write a test that reproduces it. Crucially, this new test will *still be expected to pass* if you later change the implementation, so it doesn't have the problem that the guideline was designed to avoid.